# Having Chrome Youtube playing in the background while playing a game breaks the Youtube player after a few minutes

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I just got myself a new computer, with an Intel i5 6600k, 8 GB of RAM (will be increased at a later date) and a Geforce 1070 with Windows 10. It also has a 240 GB M.2 SSD that holds both Chrome and World of Warcraft and 2 other games. I temporarily have to use a single monitor because my secondary monitor only has a VGA cable, and until I get a VGA to DisplayPort adapter so I can hook up my second monitor again, my Acer XB240H has to play Chrome Youtube in the background for some audio while I'm playing WoW in the foreground.

I've found that when I'm playing WoW while Chrome is running youtube in the background (something I didn't have issues with on my old PC with much lesser specs and 2 monitors), Youtube after a few minutes (usually about 5 to 15) starts buffering for some reason, but it also makes it so Chrome becomes unresponsive and I have to force close it and then reopen my tabs from a crash afterwards. I've had task manager open during this, and I'm not running out of memory or CPU.

In the most recent attempt, the Youtube video I was watching a few minutes ago started buffering at exactly 9 minutes. other tabs remain responsive, I can even start a different Youtube video in a different tab, and I can refresh other tabs and even load Youtube comments beneath the video that started buffering. It's once I start using the tab of the buffering video for clicking on links or refreshing the page that it breaks.

I feel like this is some kind of setting somewhere in Chrome or Windows that makes it so videos are stopped after a certain amount of the tab being not visible, but I may be wrong on this. Is there something I can do that makes it so that Youtube videos in the background still remain loaded and playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found this was caused by hardware accelleration not working properly. I disabled it in Chrome and I haven't had issues in Chrome yet.